# What are the advantages of using JdbcTemplate over NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in spring framework?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dao, jdbctemplate

I am learning spring now, from what I've learn't so far it seems as if NamedParameterJdbcTemplate provides the same functionality as JdbcTemplate does plus it allows you to use named parameters.

So the question is first why would you use JdbcTemplate at all if you can always use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate instead, so that if you let's say initially had not intended to use named parameters in your DAO class but then for some reason you decided to use them you will not need to adjust the whole DAO class?

Now the second question is why did they create this class in the first place, wouldn't it be better to have one JdbcTemplate that provides named parameters functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** - original response was inaccurate in terms of what the base `JDBCTemplate` can support and how it works; I've been dealing with too many frameworks over the years...  Here's a more accurate version:

In general, I doubt there's a compelling reason to use the `JdbcTemplate` class.

There is some overhead in supporting named parameters.  This generally requires translating the named parameters to positional parameters for use with JDBC.  If you have a lot of parameters this could add up to a lot of overhead; if you have no parameters at all, then it still imposes some overhead (the string has to be examined looking for named parameters) but in most cases that probably doesn't amount to much.

Comment: JDBC (AFAIK) doesn't even support named parameters it only supports wildcards/indexed parameters. Springs `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` is replacing the named parameters with wildcards and does so by replacing it in a `String`. So when using a `Collection` and using something like `in (:collection)`. It will replace `:collection` with the correct amount of `?`. So there is overhead in using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and depending on the number of parameters it might be significant even.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, based on what you said "There is some overhead in supporting named parameters. Typically it  means using prepared statements under the hood, rather than 
regular old statements"

I know we can use indexed parameters in JdbcTemplate, for example, like this `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("Select name from circles where id=?", new Object[] { id },String.class);`, doesn't it mean that prepared statement will be used here for JdbcTemplate under the hood as well?

Comment: I was thinking of a different framework; hazard of working in too many languages and environments.  Updating answer ...